# Python3: how to run java class file from python

Tags: java, python, python-3.x

I read JPype documentation from this link: http://jpype.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, but i am not sure that i can use JPype or it is better that i choose another way to run java class from python3. Also i have to point that i get a little confused for doing with JPype.
i did this:

```
    import urllib.request
    import os
    import tempfile
    import sys
    import fileinput
    import logging
    import JPype as jp



# here i have python code and do something else
"""
        my python code



"""

#from this point till end of the code i did for my question



    logging.basicConfig(filename="ERROR.txt", level= logging.ERROR)
    try:
        logging.debug('we are in the main try loop')

        jp.startJVM("C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/ClassWithTest.java", "-ea")
        test_class = jp.JClass("ClassWithTest")
        a = testAll()
        file_java_class = open("OUTPUT.txt", "w")
        file_java_class.write(a)
    except Exception as e1:
            logging.error(str(e1))
            jp.shutdownJVM()
```

- But it has problem and shows me this error: 7, in  import
  jpype as jp ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jpype'

========================================================================

- I have to point that my java class is in my python path and my java
  class is:

> ```
>  public class ClassWithTest{
>         public ClassWithTest(){
>       /* Va invocato */
>       System.out.println(insertLength("Tests ready to run"));
>         }
>
>         public void testAbs(){
>       /* Va invocato */
>       System.out.println(insertLength("Invocation of " + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName()));
>       System.out.println(insertLength("abs(-2) = 2: " + testResult(Math.abs(-2), 2)));
>       System.out.println(insertLength("abs(-3) = -2: " + testResult(Math.abs(-3), -2)));
>         }
>
>         public void testRound(){
>       /* Va invocato */
>       System.out.println(insertLength("Invocation of " + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName()));
>       System.out.println(insertLength("round(0.7) = 1: " + testResult(Math.round(0.7), 1)));
>       System.out.println(insertLength("round(0.2) = 1: " + testResult(Math.round(0.2), 1)));
>         }
>
>         public void testMin(){
>       /* Va invocato */
>       System.out.println(insertLength("Invocation of " + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName()));
>       System.out.println(insertLength("min(7,3) = 3: " + testResult(Math.min(7,3), 3)));
>       System.out.println(insertLength("min(5,7) = 7: " + testResult(Math.min(5,7), 7)));
>         }
>
>         public void testMax(){
>       /* Va invocato */
>       System.out.println(insertLength("Invocation of " + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName()));
>       System.out.println(insertLength("max(7,14) = 14: " + testResult(Math.max(7,14), 14)));
>       System.out.println(insertLength("max(5,7) = 5: " + testResult(Math.max(5,7), 5)));
>         }
>
>         public void TestDiv(){
>       /* Non andreabbe chiamato */
>       System.out.println(insertLength("Invocation of " + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName()));
>       System.out.println(insertLength("14 / 2 = 7: " + testResult(14 / 7, 3)));
>       //  assert(14 / 0 == 10));
>         }
>
>         public void testMult(int x){
>       /* Non andreabbe chiamato */
>       System.out.println(insertLength("Invocation of " + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName()));
>       System.out.printf("2 * %d = %s:", x, testResult(2 * x, 2 * x)));
>       //       assert(false));
>         }
>
>         public void otherTest(){
>       /* Non andreabbe chiamato */
>       System.out.println(insertLength("Invocation of " + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName()));
>       System.out.printf("1 = 1:", testResult(1, 1)));
>       //       assert(false));
>         }
>
>         private void testAll(){
>       /* Non dovrebbe essere chiamato */
>       System.out.println(insertLength("Invocation of " + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName()));
>       testAbs());
>       testRound());
>       testMin());
>       testMax());
>         }
>
>         private static String testResult(double result, double expected){
>       return (result == expected ? "ok" : "no"));
>         }
>
>     public static String insertLength(Object obj){
>         String line = obj.toString());
>         return String.format("[%d]> %s", line.length(), line));
>     }
>
>         public static void main(String[] args){
>       (new ClassWithTest()).testAll());
>         }
>     }
> ```

---

1. i do not know why this not work?!! i read jython, but i can not use
   jython, because i did not understand well. could you help me:
2. 1- how can i run java class from python  2- save the out put of
   execution in text file 3- save the possible error messages in
   another text file and then terminate. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I normally use JYthon. Making use of Java from within Jython applications is about as seamless as using external Jython modules within a Jython script.

Here is a simple example:

```
from java.lang import Math

Math.max(4, 7)

Math.pow(10,5)

from java.lang import System as javasystem
javasystem.out.println("Hello")
Hello
```

Comment: I get confused, i did read documents about JYthon but i did not understand this: my java file is in my python path and how can i define in this : from .... import .... that from my java file path import my java file???

Comment: and also what about my java class? because inside java file i have a class which has too many different functions that i have to invoke all from main method and save out put in text file